# What are the factors that affect the dampening of spring-mass system?

Tags: friction, spring, drag, oscillators, dissipation

I'm trying to investigate how different values of spring constant affect the changes in amplitude and period of oscillations while the spring-mass system undergoes dampening. However, I have to make sure that the way I change spring constant does not affect my experiment.

1. Does using different materials to change the spring constant affect the dampening?
2. Does the mass of the spring affect dampening?
3. What are other constraints?

Plus, as the spring-mass system undergoes dampening, I'm going to look at successive amplitude values to figure out the decaying constant for each value of spring constant. For different values of spring constant, if I begin with the same initial amplitude, the total energy of the system will vary. If I set the experiment so that all trials begin with the same total energy of the system, the amplitude will vary.

4. Which one (initial amplitude or total energy) should I keep constant to figure out valid decaying constant?

Answer (score -1):

We should remember that damping of spring mass system is due to drag from air. Many think friction is cause of dampening but you see in vertical spring mass system like weight (gravitational force) does not affect the time period to change over time similarly a constant forces are to ignored (note force must not change direction and magnitude). So we shouldn't consider constant forces as sources of dampening. We have to consider forces that are proportional to speed,speed square,distance from origin etc.(Because mathematically they will change the differential equation of constant time period to decaying time period)

*So answer to your questions*
1. No changing the spring material will change spring constant. It will merely add anything to drag force.

2. No mass of spring will not cause dampening oscillation.
   In that case time period is given by
   $$ T=2π√((m(obj)+(m(spring))/3))/k$$
3. The area of object is the other factor that causes mainly the drag.
   $$F(drag)=(density of air)*(area)*(speed)^2$$ 
   So use small bob.

4.$$E(system)=(KA^2)/2$$
I think  Try to keep amplitude constant in all trials it will  be easy to find decaying constant.And initial  energy will more if a constant larger amplitude so it will decay very less.

Comment: Of course spring material will matter too. And why assume that the forces are proportional to velocity? Also: damping affects the frequency of oscillation.

Comment: @Pieter forces should be proportional to speed or speed square or derivatives of distance from origin or else they have to be changing direction to cause dampening and away from origin for some part of oscillation.And spring material does not matter.If it matters then explain how.

Comment: Have you ever seen a tuning fork made of plastic? Also sliding friction or rolling friction reverses direction. Amonton/Coulomb friction does not depend on speed.

Comment: @Pieter He is asking about spring mass system why should I consider a tuning fork.And moreover a tunning fork of plastic is not used  as it cannot produce that audible frequency and it would deform.plastic or material does not cause any dampening until it is out of elastic limit.And frictional forces does not cause dampening.(you can see by solving differential equation)

Comment: @Pieter please reply to my above comment i want to know whether i am correct

Comment: A tuning fork is a mass-spring system. But if you interpret spring-mass system narrowly as having a coiled spring, a plastic spring would clearly have move internal damping than a steel spring. And why would Amonton friction not cause damping? Just because one cannot write an analytical differential equation for that?

Comment: @Pieter So could you answer my questions? I need the answers as soon as possible... I'll really appreciate it if you answer my questions.

Comment: @동휘민 It was me who voted to close your question. This site is not for doing your homework.